# How to select a number without replacement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm trying to make a mix and match between numbers here is my code

```
import random

P1 = float(input("Person's name?")) 
P2 = float(input("Person's name?")) 
P3 = float(input("Person's name?"))

A1 = float(input("Activity?")) 
A2 = float(input("Activity?")) 
A3 = float(input("Activity?")) 

s = (A1, A2, A3)

cool1 = random.sample([A1, A2, A3],1)
cool2 = random.sample([A1, A2, A3],1)
cool3 = random.sample([A1, A2, A3],1)


print ("%s job is %s." %(P1, cool1))

print ("%s job is %s." %(P2, cool2))

print ("%s job is %s." %(P3, cool3))
```

The problem is that it is randomizing but it keeps repeating numbers like here

**

> 1.0 job is [4.0].
>   2.0 job is [5.0].
>   3.0 job is [4.0].

**

What can I do to make it not repeat.
I'm using python 2.7.12

Also how can I use alphanumerical instead of float only.

Comment: what do you mean repeating? Are you talking about how job 1 and 3 returned the same number?

Comment: Exactly :) @depperm

Comment: `cool1, cool2, cool3 = random.sample([A1, A2, A3], 3)`? Or just shuffle then assign.

Comment: @CoolBro so am I correct in assuming you want the 3 activity numbers to be randomly assigned to a person but so that each is assigned only once?

Comment: Why would you prompt for a name and then expect the user to enter a float?  That just makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it came out like this 1.0 job is [4.0, 6.0, 5.0].
2.0 job is [6.0, 5.0, 4.0].
3.0 job is [4.0, 6.0, 5.0].

Comment: So you want each to be a unique permutation? Then why not create a list of permutations (see `itertools`), shuffle it and pick from that.

Comment: yup right on the dot m8 @depperm

Comment: @CoolBro: Added an answer and I think you may find it useful (I don't know who downvoted it)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Someone seems to be downvoting any answer posted to this question

Comment: Thanks everyone I fixed the problem :)

Comment: @CoolBro Please upvote and accept the answers you found useful. It will help others who are going to face the similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to achieve this will be to use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) (if you want to randomize the original sample list) or [`random.select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) (if you want to keep the original sample copy):

*Example with `random.shuffle`:*

```
>>> import random
>>> my_samples = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
>>> shuffle(my_samples)
>>> cool1, cool2, cool3 = my_samples
# Random Result: cool1 = 'A3', cool2='A1', cool3='A2'
```

*Example with `random.select`:*

```
>>> cool1, cool2, cool3 = random.sample(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 3)
```

---

If you want minimal changes in your solution. You may remove an entry from your samples based on random selection and get next choice from remaining samples like:

```
>>> import random
>>> cool1 = random.sample(my_samples,1)
>>> my_samples.remove(*cool1)
>>> my_samples
['A1', 'A3']
>>> cool2 = random.sample(my_samples,1)
>>> my_samples.remove(*cool2)
>>> cool3 = random.sample(my_samples,1)
>>> my_samples.remove(*cool3)
>>> my_samples 
[]
>>> cool1, cool2, cool3
(['A2'], ['A3'], ['A1'])
```

Comment: @DownVoter: Please would you care to explain the reason as well?

Answer (score 1):

write a class to pick a unique element from list
1. permutations finds all unique elements 
2. rest can define new data and length of result

```
from itertools import permutations
class PickOne( object ):
    def __init__(self,lst,l):
        self.lst    = lst
        self.visit  = set()
        self.l      =  l 
        self.lenght = self.number(l)
    def pick(self):
        if len(self.visit) == self.lenght :
            print 'run out numbers'
            return 
        res = tuple(random.sample(self.lst,self.l))
        while res in self.visit:
            res = tuple(random.sample(self.lst,self.l))
        self.visit.add( res )
        return res
    def reset(self,l,lst = None):
        if not lst:
            lst = self.lst
        self.__init__(lst,l)

    def number(self,l):
        return len( list(permutations(self.lst,l)) )
```

Example:

```
 a = PickOne([1,2,3,4],1)
    >>> a.pick()
    (2,)
    >>> a.pick()
    (1,)
    >>> a.pick()
    (4,)
    >>> a.pick()
    (3,)
    >>> a.pick()
    run out numbers

    >>> a.reset(2)
    >>> a.pick()
    (3, 1)
    >>> a.pick()
    (3, 4)
    >>> a.pick()
    (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting from a list, then you should delete the entry from the list after each check.

1. Create your original list, which will be used as needed.
2. Create a second list from the first to use as you select.
3. As you choose each element from the list, remove it
4. Put the chosen element into a list of chosen element.

[Python remove method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_remove.htm)

> **Parameters**
>   obj -- This is the object to be removed from the list.
>
> **Return Value**
>   This method does not return any value but removes the
>   given object from the list.
>
> **Example**
>    The following example shows the usage of remove() method.
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
>
> aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz'];
>
> aList.remove('xyz');
> print "List : ", aList
> aList.remove('abc');
> print "List : ", aList
> ```
>
> When we run above program, it produces following result −
>
> ```
> List :  [123, 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz']
> List :  [123, 'zara', 'xyz']
> ```

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
cool1, cool2, cool3 = random.sample([A1, A2, A3], 3)
```

> Also how can I use alphanumerical instead of float only.

Have you tried not converting your inputs to float...?